# Some Google Map Markers not showing up in Internet Explorer but show up in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps, cross-browser

I have a Google Map on our site that has a list of markers which are brought in using the following code:

```
$(".map-overlay-right").click(function () {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map-holder'));
    $("#map-holder").fadeOut('slow', function(){                                    
        var gmarkers = [];  
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());

        $.get("http://afid.staging.dante-studios.com/xml-feed-google-maps",{},function(xml) {
            $('marker',xml).each(function(i) {
                html = $(this).text();
                lat = $(this).attr("lat");
                lng = $(this).attr("lng");
                label = $(this).attr("label");
                var point = new GLatLng(lat,lng);
                var marker = createMarker(point,label,html);
                map.addOverlay(marker);
            });
        });

    });
    $("#map-holder").fadeIn('slow');    
    var Asia = new GLatLng(23.684774, 90.087891);
    map.setCenter(Asia, 4); 
});
```

The XML file that brings them in looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<markers> 
    <marker id="1" lat="11.547812" lng="104.915957" label="Foo"> 
        <infowindow> 
            <![CDATA[HTML GOES HERE]]>
        </infowindow> 
    </marker> 
    <marker id="2" lat="11.547812" lng="104.915957" label="Bar"> 
        <infowindow> 
            <![CDATA[HTML GOES HERE]]>
        </infowindow> 
    </marker> 
    <marker id="3" lat="11.547812" lng="104.915957" label="Baz"> 
        <infowindow> 
            <![CDATA[HTML GOES HERE]]>
        </infowindow> 
    </marker>  
</markers>
```

For some reason not all the markers show up in Internet Explorer.  IE throws this error:

Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; OfficeLiveConnector.1.4; OfficeLivePatch.1.3)
Timestamp: Thu, 17 Dec 2009 12:39:16 UTC


Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 143
Char: 18
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/193c/maps2.api/main.js
```

But the rest of the browsers seem to be ok and behaving well.  The part of the code that throws the error is this bit:

```
map.addOverlay(marker);
```

The site can be seen here: http://afid.staging.dante-studios.com/ and clicking on Asia will best show the error as the markers at the bottom of india show up on all browsers but not in IE.

I've spent a while trying to resolve this but i'm not getting anywhere. If anyone can shed some light on this i would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marker 42 in your marker [XML](http://afid.staging.dante-studios.com/xml-feed-google-maps) has a malformed latitude:

```
<marker id="42" lat="-12.968270," lng="28.633699" label="Ndola, Zambia">
```

Note the trailing comma in the `lat` attribute.

Comment: Actually when i opened it in IE and it barfed, it allowed me to debug it with Visual Studio. I figured it was a bogus marker so after a bit of stack navigation i found the offending latitude value, then just searched for it in the XML.