# “Invalid argument main.js” Gmap error in IE

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, drupal-6

i have Gmap and Gmap Location vesion  6.x-1.1.
in IE (any version) when i see Gmap Page I can see this error:

```
Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 401
Char: 18
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/fa_ALL/mapfiles/310c/maps2.api/main.js
```

i find this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921528/some-google-map-markers-not-showing-up-in-internet-explorer-but-show-up-in-all-ot) but my lan , lat parameter are true.

what is problem?

[link to main.js](http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/fa_ALL/mapfiles/310c/maps2.api/main.js)
line 401 :  `function Gg(a,b){a.style.left=S(b)}`

Comment: Has this worked for you once?

Comment: Remove the last changes you did to your code and check if it works (again). If not, remove as long as it works.

Comment: this is drupal module. i didnt change it

Comment: Please add that information to your question. Tell the name of the drupal module and add a link.

Comment: That comment was just meant to be helpful, if it bothers you, just ignore. But I think for others who might want to answer your question it would be comparable as hard as it was for me to gather that information right upfront from your question. Just saying so, others are probably much better with this, so please don't feel offended.

Comment: Post the code that calls this. It's most likely a problem in the *calling* code, not GMap's `main.js`

Comment: this is  a drupal module Pekka.